# Replance first and last Char?

Tags: java, string

How do I replace the *first* and *last* character in the following code? I have no idea how to do it. **(I'm a beginner)** Thank you. (I know my `modifiedValue = temp.substring(0, 6);` line is wrong as I already used it in a previous line.)

```
public void switched() {
    String temp;
    String modifiedValue;

    temp = inputField.getText();
    modifiedValue = temp.substring(0, 6);
    outputArea.append("With first char last and last char first:\n");
    outputArea.append("\t" + modifiedValue + "\n");
    outputArea.append("\n");

} // end of switched()
```

Answer (score 3):

To swap the first and last characters of a string, try this:

```
int n = temp.length();
temp = temp.charAt(n-1) + temp.substring(1, n-1) + temp.charAt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work

```
int n = temp.length();
temp = temp.substring(n-1) + temp.substring(1,n-1)+temp.substring(0,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

u may try:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("foo bar");
System.out.println(sb); // foo bar
sb.append(sb.charAt(0));
sb.setCharAt(0, sb.charAt(sb.length() - 2));
sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 2);
System.out.println(sb); // roo baf
```